# Struts 2.2.1.1 API Javadocs

Tags: api, struts2

I am not able to locate the struts 2.2.1.1 API docs (the javadocs).
Does anybody have a referece/know where can i get a dump of this?

The struts documentation distribution does not seem have the API file, it points to

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/index.html

which does not exist. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.2.1.1/struts2-core-2.2.1.1-javadoc.jar!/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Bug and solved in next version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3586

You can download the current api docs here.
http://people.apache.org/builds/struts/2.2.2/

Comment: even the link you provided, http://people.apache.org/builds/struts/2.2.2/    shows 404 error. Seems like its not yet fixed.